# Javascript IE Events, this

Tags: javascript, events, this, compatibility, explorer

Okay so, I have  alist of links, I'm processing them with a for loop, attaching events.
The links get a click event that calls a function. The function needs to operate on the object that called it. Like so:

```
  <ul><li id = 'myId'>Text</li>
    <li id = 'myId'>Text</li>
    <li id = 'myId'>Text</li>
    <li id = 'myId'>Text</li>
    </ul>


   var grab = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
   for (var x =0;x<grab.length;x++){
       grab[x].attachEvent('onmouseover',doSomething);
       }

    function doSomething(){
        this.setAttribute('color','yellow');
    }
```

This worked fine in all browsers but IE, the problem I'm having there seems to be that IE wants 'this' to be the window, rather than the object that called the event.

I get that JQuery solves this problem really easily, its just that I don't have access to JQuery in this context.Is there a way, just within regular javascript, to get IE using 'this' correctly, or a way to approximate the behaviour that everybody else has?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the old standard reliable `on[event]` handlers.

```
for (var x = 0, len = grab.length; x < len; x++) { 
   grab[x].onmouseover = doSomething;
}
```

And make sure you're not actually duplicating IDs as shown in the question.

Comment: Thanks, they were dummmy id's, I wanted to use this style of event registration, but I also want to register an onmouseleave event (or whatever IE calls it) is that possible when use use this type of event handler?

Comment: @user173361: Yes, you can bind a handler for any type of supported event, though you should use `onmouseout` to complement the `onmouseover`.

Answer (score 1):

I think the event is passed to the function, you should be able to use `evt.srcElement`

```
for (var x =0;x<grab.length;x++){
       grab[x].attachEvent('onmouseover', doSomething);
 }

 function doSomething(evt){
     evt.srcElement.setAttribute('color','yellow');
 }
```

Comment: You need to have `doSomething` return a function. EDIT: Your update won't work either, because you're back to the original problem of `this` not being a reference to the element that received the event.

Comment: Go back to your first answer, but inside `doSomething`, have it `return function() { sender.setAttribute('color','yellow'); };` So you're returning a function that closes over `sender`. Not sure if there are closure leaks in IE, but it'll work for the problem at hand.

Comment: Okay, I do have kind of a dumb look, 'this' passed as a paramater gives me an 'object' event, which I think is still not what I want, it gives an id of 'undefined' anyways?

Comment: @user173361 I think you can use `evt.srcElement` as replacement for `this`. See update

Comment: Hope it doesn't seem like I'm picking on you, but that'll only work in IE, or maybe Chrome since they emulate some of the IE stuff, but not in other browsers. Also, it's equivalent to `evt.target`, which will be different from the `this` if there are nested elements clicked.

Comment: Hey, I appreciate the help, srcElement is not firing for me, I think I'll just rewrite with those old events. Your solution is closer to what I want, i just am out of time. Thanks for the good help though.

Comment: @cliffsofinsanity Yes its IE only as specified in the question. Also i I remember correctly attachEvent is also IE only (addEventListener otherwize)

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this:

```
<ul><li id = 'myId'>Text</li>
<li id = 'myId'>Text</li>
<li id = 'myId'>Text</li>
<li id = 'myId'>Text</li>
</ul>

var grab = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
for (var x =0;x<grab.length;x++){
    grab[x].attachEvent('onmouseover',function(){
        doSomething.call(grab[x]);
    });
}
function doSomething(){
    this.setAttribute('color','yellow');
}
```

Comment: That won't work because JavaScript doesn't have block scope. The same `x` variable is referenced by every handler, so every handler will reference the final value to which `x` was set after the loop. You'd need a closure to retain each iteration value.